# How to make inactive multiple line R code in a script

Tags: r

I do have a long R script and I don't want to delete a part of this R script. Is there any way to avoid running this multiple line R code in the script or should I need to insert # at the beginning of each of these lines?

I don't want to run this whole below code but want to run the code which follow it?

```
   alpha = 0.01
    sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3 = resTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3[which(resTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$padj < alpha), ]
    sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3 = cbind(as(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3, "data.frame"), as(tax_table(physeq6Genus)[rownames(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3), ], "matrix"))
    head(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3)
    dim(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3)

    library("ggplot2")
    theme_set(theme_bw())
    scale_fill_discrete <- function(palname = "Set1", ...) {
        scale_fill_brewer(palette = palname, ...)
    }
    # Phylum order
    x = tapply(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$log2FoldChange, sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$Phylum, function(x) max(x))
    x = sort(x, TRUE)
    sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$Phylum = factor(as.character(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$Phylum), levels=names(x))
    # Genus order
    x = tapply(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$log2FoldChange, sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$Genus, function(x) max(x))
    x = sort(x, TRUE)
    sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$Genus = factor(as.character(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3$Genus), levels=names(x))

    pdf("DESeq2-Soil-batch1-DEG-T1_vs_T3_pval.01.pdf", width = 8, height = 6);
    ggplot(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3, aes(x=Genus, y=log2FoldChange, color=Phylum)) + geom_point(size=6)+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0, vjust=0.5))
    dev.off();

    write.csv(sigtabresTreatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3,"sigResult-Treatment6Genus_T1_vs_T3")

###############
Further R code that needs to run

###########
```

Many thanks
Yogesh

Comment: All good editors support commenting/uncommenting a block of lines at once. How this works depends on the editor. Apart from that, the correct solution to the problem “I have a bunch of code I want to disable but don’t want to remove” is to use a version control system, and to create a branch.

Comment: If you want a janky solution wrap it all in `if(0==1){ ... }`

Comment: @DanielO Why `0==1`? Why not `length(grep("foo",bar"))>1`?